# Applescript - remember state between executions?

Tags: applescript

Some Applescripts I have used have remembered state between executions, e.g., location for Open/Save dialogues.

Now I have written an AS that takes a string as input from the user (via a `display dialog`). I would like the script to remember that string between executions. Possible? How?

Comment: You have two choices, assign it as the _value_ of a `property` or write it to a disk file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the string a property, it will remember that string between executions, **until the next time you open up and re-save the script**.

Here’s an example:

```
property myName : ""

if myName is "" then
    display dialog "What is your name?" default answer ""
    set myName to the text returned of the result
end if

display notification "Hello, " & myName
```

Save the script as an “Application”, “Script”, or “Script bundle”. If saved as “Text” (or if run from Script Editor) it will not maintain properties between runs.

The first time you run it, it will notice that `myName` is the empty string and request your name.

Subsequent times you run it, it will already have your name in the property `myName`.

If you open the script again, and then resave the script, this resets all properties. If you need the script to retain data through edits, you’ll need to save it in a database, which could be as simple as a text file in a central location.

```
set nameFile to POSIX file "/Users/USERNAME/name.txt"

tell application "Finder"
    if exists nameFile then
        set nameFileHandle to open for access nameFile
        set myName to read nameFileHandle
        close access nameFileHandle
    else
        display dialog "What is your name?" default answer ""
        set myName to the text returned of the result
        set nameFileHandle to open for access nameFile with write permission
        write myName to nameFileHandle
        close access nameFileHandle
    end if
end tell

display notification "Hello, " & myName
```

In this case the variable `nameFile` doesn’t need to be a property since it never changes. Because it doesn’t need to be a property, this version also does not need to be saved as non-Text, and can even be run from Script Editor.

It is also *very* simple; if you need to store and retrieve multiple items, you would need to follow up on the “File Read/Write” section of “StandardAdditions”. You can get there from Script Editor under “File:Open Dictionary…”.

For more complex memory, you may find the “Property List Suite” in the “System Events” dictionary useful.

Comment: I run the script from Script Menu - does it work with just a compiled script and/or does Script Menu work with applications?

Comment: Applications do work with Script Menu, but you can save as any non-Text form.

Comment: I will say that for long term usage an app might be better however if the app or script is reopened in Script Editor it is reset as opening it in Script Editor automatically recompiles the code. IMO persistent data should be written to a separate disk file.

Comment: Saving to a file or using the defaults system is also the way to go with current systems if the app is scripting other applications - properties and globals have historically been saved _in the script file itself_ (by modifying it), which can result in accessibility issues.